# Dynamic Dropdown list with actions

Tags: html, ajax, django, drop-down-menu, django-forms

like 1 [image](http://bit.ly/1ocI0X) says more than 1000 words. here is what I want to implement in a django webapp:

http://bit.ly/1ocI0X

Is a dynamic dropdown list with an action to add values to db and dynamicly added to self dropdownlist.

Any hint would be appreciated. Tks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with Django, but as long as you can make ajax calls you're good to go. Using jQuery on the client side would probably make this easier.

If the user selects `<New User>` from your dropdown, you pop up a form, submit the form with ajax and the response from the server would preferably be json containing the new user's details. Then you insert the json data into your select element.

Comment: Look easy. Im going to try my best with jquery, Thank you. This have to have a name of this 'Ajax UI feature' dont you think?.